# Как пишется "еще (не) известны"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

*Однако технические детали проекта еще (не)известны, что порождает вопросы и беспокойство.* Похожий вопрос уже был, но у меня все равно сомнения. "(Не)известны" в данном предложении пишется раздельно из-за наличия слова "еще"? (Предложение - цитата, важно сохранить дословно).

Answer (score 7):

**Оба варианта возможны, оба встречаются в Нацкорпусе** (не известны ― 24 примера, неизвестны ― 48 примеров).

Мы знаем, что **зависимые слова не влияют на написание НЕ с прилагательными,** в то в время как с причастиями НЕ при наличии зависимых слов пишется раздельно.

Но это краткая форма является сказуемым, а в этом случае возможен **авторский выбор:** отрицание признака или утверждение противоположного признака. В то же время наречие ***еще*** имеет временное значение, что сближает прилагательное с причастием.

Все эти факторы и приводят к разным решениям. **Можно проверить семантику,** сравнив такие варианты: были еще неизвестны и  были **(пока)** еще неизвестны. Если логически выделен смысл "пока еще", то лучше писать раздельно.

Примеры:

Но в то время истины эти **были еще неизвестны**, и репутация сердцеведца утвердилась за Грустиловым беспрепятственно. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. История одного города (1869-1870)

Пределы свободы **были еще не известны обществу** и не определены властью. [Давид Самойлов. Общий дневник (1977-1989)]

А вот **усиление отрицания** (только раздельное написание): Но **никому еще не известны** практические свойства вещества. [В. Станцо. Ученые ищут, ученые находят // «Химия и жизнь», 1965]